# Customized bar showed on most of View controllers

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone give me a hint? 
i have an customized bar (with some buttons and images) bellow the navigation bar.
What i want is this customized bar has to be showed on most of the view controllers (not all of them). Is there a good way to do it?

What i know is that. I might create an xib with this bar only and instantiate it in the view controllers according to the needs. But that means, i would need to write the instantiate code on all of swift file.

Can container view controller be used for solving this problem?

Comment: Why not subclass your second bar from UIView? And then just put this UIView subclass on the controllers you want them on in the Storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension UIViewController {

   func showCustomBar()  {
      // create here and add to nav bar (if any)
   }

   func hideCustomBar()  {
      // remove the bar (if any)
   }

}
```

Now all you have to do in your view controllers is

```
self.showCustomBar()
```